# How to avoid false positive on SQL query checking for IS NULL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

How to avoid false positive on SQL query checking for IS NULL?

I seemed to have corrected my false positives by adding the `if(sqlsrv_has_rows` statement.

PHP:

```
/*

IF select of 1900 datein has rows
update datein

IF select of 1900 dateout has rows
update dateout

IF select of 1900 datein AND dateout no rows
insert datein

*/
$datein_s="SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein='1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC";
$datein_sr=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_s,$params) or die("Error datein:".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
$datein=sqlsrv_fetch($datein_sr);
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($datein_sr)===FALSE)
{
$datein="NOROWS";
}
else
{
$datein="HASROWS";
}

$dateout_s="SELECT TOP 1 dateout FROM clocked WHERE dateout='1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND userid=? ORDER BY dateout DESC";
$dateout_sr=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$dateout_s,$params) or die("Error dateout:".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
$dateout=sqlsrv_fetch($dateout_sr);
echo $dateout;
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($dateout_sr)===FALSE)
{
$dateout="NOROWS";
}
else
{
$dateout="HASROWS";
}

if($datein==="HASROWS")
{
$datein_q1="UPDATE clocked SET datein=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 datein FROM clocked WHERE datein='1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND userid=? ORDER BY datein DESC);";
$datein_qr1=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q1,$params) or die("Error update datein:".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
echo "Datein and out are HASROWS";
}
else if ($dateout==="HASROWS")
{
$dateout_q1="UPDATE clocked SET dateout=GETDATE() WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 dateout FROM clocked WHERE dateout='1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND userid=? ORDER BY dateout DESC);";
$dateout_qr1=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$dateout_q1,$params) or die("Error update dateout:".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
echo "Dateout NOROWS";
}
else if ($datein==="NOROWS"&&$dateout==="NOROWS")
{
$datein_q2="INSERT INTO clocked(datein,userid) VALUES(GETDATE(),?);";
$datein_qr2=sqlsrv_query($dbconnect,$datein_q2,$params) or die("Error insert datein:".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
echo "Datein and Dateout NOROWS";
}
else
{
echo "ERROR your query may be broken!";
}
```

Comment: Check the number of rows in the result set, before you try to pull any values out from any of the fields (in your php, not SQL).

Comment: NULL = "unkown value". Not true/false/empty.  `item` TEXT DEFAULT NULL. if($item !== NULL)

Comment: If NULL is not Empty, then why is that the only other accepted value for a date/datetime field? @Philip

Comment: datetime accepts values that have not been set, ie: unkown value: NULL

Comment: @Philip How would you suggest setting empty datetimes?

Comment: you could use: `somedate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: @Philip It seems SQLSRV won't let me insert that value.

Comment: somedate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is a SQL table config

Comment: @Philip so it will let you default it to all 0 but won't let you insert that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seemed to have corrected my false positives by adding the if(sqlsrv_has_rows statement.